# NTFS Permissions not behaving as expected

Tags: permissions

I have several hundred folders in a directory where somehow, the permissions have become all messed up. When I'm trying to take ownership with my domain admin account, I tick the box which says `Replace owner on subcontainers and objects` but the resulting changes do not apply to many of the sub-folders. I also want to use the `Replace all child object permission entries with inheritable permission entries from this object`.
I then have to go to each one (and there are quite literally hundreds) and set the owner on each one. This is a daunting task and there must be some way of achieving this en-masse. Currently I'm having to click the `Continue` button for hundreds of failed 'take ownership' attempts.
I've looked at the `ICACLS` and `takeown` commands but I can't figure out what I can use to force ownership onto folders although I have been able to bypass prematurely wearing out my mouse button with the `/C` switch.
Can anyone help please?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Windows `Explorer` has many problems dealing with a deep nested directory layout, *especially* when changing owner/ACL.

I strongly suggest using [`SetACL Studio`](https://helgeklein.com/setacl-studio/) or the relative command line program `SetACL`. They are both free utilities which do their job. Compared to them, `CACLS`, `ICACLS`, `takeown` and the likes seem relatively primitive tools.